# DocuSign API setAnchorString limit to SetPageNumber not working

Tags: laravel, api, docusignapi

I am trying to get dynamic initial tabs on Anchor text at specified page numbers. This is part of my InitialTab:

```
{
    "anchorCaseSensitive": "true",
    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
    "anchorMatchWholeWord": "true",
    "anchorString": "PDF File",
    "anchorUnits": "inches",
    "anchorXOffset": 1,
    "anchorYOffset": 1,
    "documentId": "1",
    "pageNumber": "6",
    "recipientId": "1"
}{
    "anchorCaseSensitive": "true",
    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
    "anchorMatchWholeWord": "true",
    "anchorString": "PDF File",
    "anchorUnits": "inches",
    "anchorXOffset": 1,
    "anchorYOffset": 1,
    "documentId": "1",
    "pageNumber": "6",
    "recipientId": "1"
}
```

With that i get double tabs on same place on both pages 5 and 6. One on top of the other. 
[image: Double tabs issue]

Using https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client and default configuration options:

```
${'initialtab' . $i} = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\InitialHere();
${'initialtab' . $i}->setAnchorString($documentfield->anchorstring);
${'initialtab' . $i}->setAnchorXOffset($documentfield->positionx);
${'initialtab' . $i}->setAnchorYOffset($documentfield->positiony);
${'initialtab' . $i}->setAnchorUnits("inches");                            
${'initialtab' . $i}->setAnchorCaseSensitive("true");
${'initialtab' . $i}->setAnchorMatchWholeWord("true");
${'initialtab' . $i}->setAnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent("true");
${'initialtab' . $i}->setPageNumber("$i");
${'initialtab' . $i}->setDocumentId("1");
${'initialtab' . $i}->setRecipientId("1");
$clientInitialHereTabs[] = ${'initialtab' . $i};
```

If word matches it adds Initial tabs on every page where that word exists.

When i try to use tab position by X and Y coordinates it works by page number. Otherwise not

```
${'initialtab' . $i} = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\InitialHere();
${'initialtab' . $i}->setXPosition("300");
${'initialtab' . $i}->setYPosition("100");
${'initialtab' . $i}->setDocumentId("1");
${'initialtab' . $i}->setPageNumber("1");
${'initialtab' . $i}->setRecipientId("1");
```

Is there any option to limit that based on page number?

Tried with ${'initialtab' . $i}->setPageNumber("1"); and ${'initialtab' . $i}->setPageNumber(1); and other things but no luck. It's ignoring setPageNumber

{
    "anchorCaseSensitive": "true",
    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
    "anchorMatchWholeWord": "true",
    "anchorString": "PDF File",
    "anchorUnits": "inches",
    "anchorXOffset": 1,
    "anchorYOffset": 1,
    "documentId": "1",
    "pageNumber": "6",
    "recipientId": "1"
}{
    "anchorCaseSensitive": "true",
    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
    "anchorMatchWholeWord": "true",
    "anchorString": "PDF File",
    "anchorUnits": "inches",
    "anchorXOffset": 1,
    "anchorYOffset": 1,
    "documentId": "1",
    "pageNumber": "6",
    "recipientId": "1"
}

One InitialTab one page 5 and other on page 6.  Not double ones on same place.

Here is function for SetPageNumber https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client/blob/master/src/Model/DateSigned.php#L41

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anchor tabs can't be limited by page.

There is an internal-only setting of `Anchor Tag Population Scope` which defaults to `envelope` but can be set to `document`. This won't help if your envelopes are a single document, but if you can break things up and use several documents it can help.

If you'd like to have that setting changed, contact your Account Manager or open a case with [DocuSign Support](https://support.docusign.com/). If you're requesting the setting be changed in Demo, mention that and provide your demo account number.

Comment: Thank you. I will use coordinates option for page specific signatures then.

Comment: That can work. Unique strings per page would be the other way to go.